# Work with sets in C++

Tags: c++, set, stdset

How can I define sets in C++ and insert values into them?

Comment: Well, you'd have to start off by learning to Google...

Comment: @Computer Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions).

Comment: I wanted to use u're knowledge!!!!

Answer (score 16):

Use the [`std::set` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) in `<set>`.

```
std::set<int> s; // define a set of ints
s.insert(1);     // insert into a set
```